# Positioning text in rows in a table

Tags: tables, beamer

I am using following code for placing table in my presentation

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Economic theory vs. Socionomic Theory}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Economic voting} & \textbf{Socionomic voting} \\
\midrule
1. Rising markets make \\ investors optimistic & Optimistic investors \\ make markets rise \\
2. Recessions result in  \\ more cautious business practices & More cautious business practices result in recessions \\
3. Scandals outrage \\ public & Outraged public seeks scandals \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

The problem is, I wish first 2 lines be under the 1st column, and 2nd 2 under 2nd - Socionomic theory. Could you please give me a hint, which command or signs should i use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] %% am using '[t]' just for this example
\frametitle{Economic Theory vs.\ Socionomic Theory}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lLL@{}}
\toprule
& \textbf{Economic voting} & \textbf{Socionomic voting} \\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){2-3}
1. & Rising markets make investors optimistic & 
Optimistic investors make markets rise \\
2. & Recessions result in more cautious business practices & 
More cautious business practices result in recessions\\
3. & Scandals outrage public & 
Outraged public seeks scandals \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! One more small question: how did you manage to place Table:Table caption in center? In my TeX it shows from right side.

Comment: @user54875 - the caption is placed centered by default, i.e., unless some other intervening instruction is provided. Do you maybe load a package that affects the positioning of `table` (and `figure`) captions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `\\` in a table without creating a new row. A solution consists in using the `makecell` package: it has `\makecell` and `\thead` commands that allow to define a common formatting of cells/column heads and support `\\`. In addition I added a column for the item numbers and emulated an enumerate environment, following ideas from the `listliketab` package (that I didn't use, as it doesn't not seem to be compatible with \makecell).

```
\documentclass[x11names]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Economic theory vs. Socionomic Theory}
\begin{table}[!h]
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\addtocounter{tabenum}{1}\thetabenum.}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\color{RoyalBlue3}}r@{\hskip\itemsep}l@{\hskip 4em} l@{}}
\toprule
 & \thead{Economic voting} & \thead{Socionomic voting} \\%
\midrule
\tabitem &\makecell {Rising markets make\\ investors optimistic} & \makecell{Optimistic investors \\ make markets rise} \\
\addlinespace
\tabitem & \makecell{Recessions result in \\ more cautious \\business practices} & \makecell{More cautious\\ business practices \\result in recessions} \\
\addlinespace
\tabitem & \makecell{Scandals outrage \\ public} & \makecell{Outraged public\\ seeks scandals} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]